# Using azure AD grants permission to all users by default.

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

When using Azure Ad in a c# application, everyone is given access to sign in to the app by default. Is this behaviour consistent and documented? If so, how would I over rcome this behavior?

I am using the code sample provided by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by default everyone in the tenant has access.

You can require user assignment by finding your app from *Enterprise applications -> All applications*, then going to *Properties*. There is a switch that says "User assignment required?".

Then from the same place you can go to the *Users and groups* tab and assign the users you want to have access.